# Geo-Redundant Read Access Cross-Region Charges

Tags: azure, azure-storage

I am working on an environment, using blob storage with Geo-Redundant Read-Access. Storage is setup in the East 2 region and Secondary Storage is replicating to the Central region.

We created a new machine in the Central region,  and I'm using AZCopy to copy files from the Secondary read-only storage endpoint.

I wanted to know if this avoids cross-zone data transfer costs since technically the Secondary storage is in Central?  It's hard to tell on the portal whether we are being charged or not.

Answer (score 0):

Since both the source and target storage accounts are in the same region, you will not be charged for data transfer as the data did not leave the region however you will be charged for read transactions on source storage account and write transactions on target storage account.

Comment: Well... true about transactions, but the transaction charges are background noise. A rounding error.

Comment: You answered my question..  Thank you!